# Visual Studio 2019 Azure KeyVault configuration error when publish

Tags: visual-studio, azure, azure-keyvault

I want to deploy my project to Azure in an App Service I have just created. Also, I created a KeyVault for all my settings.

When I try to deploy to app to the service, I have to configure the connection strings for the databases.

[image]

I click on **Configure** and follow the instruction and select the right app service or KeyVault. Then, in the last step, I receive this error.

> Dependency configuration progress
>
> Failed to resolve token 'ProfileResourceId'.
>
> ErrorEmpty parameter 'resourceId'...
>
> ErrorFailed to configure Azure AppService settings.
>
> Failed to configure dependency Azure Key Vault secrets1

[image]

How can I fix it?

### More details

I didn't follow any documentation. Usually, I use Azure DevOps to deploy application to Azure. In this case, I prefer to deploy the application from my laptop.

For that, I downloaded the publish profile from the portal and added in **Visual Studio**.

[image]

Then, I see some alert. At the beginning I ignored the alert but the deployed application doesn't work. So, I tried to configure each **dependence**.

[image]

If I press on the + to add a new service dependency, I select **Azure Key Vault**. Select the Azure subscription and the keyvault. Then, the local variable and review the setting. Then Finish.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image: 30719-image.png]

In the solution I see some files for **ServiceDependencies**

[image]

What it is strange to me is that in the project I successful configured the **Connected Services**.

[image]

Comment: There is a link in the first screen capture to configure azure KeyVault, did you try that out already? Are you logged in your visual studio instance with the same user than the one you are logged on in Azure Portal? Do you have more details on how you reached this state (minimum reproducible example) ?

Comment: I added some updates. Also, I opened a ticket on Microsoft and PSC https://www.puresourcecode.com/forum/topic/visual-studio-2019-azure-keyvault-configuration-error-when-publish/#postid-57

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with Application Insights. I was able to resolve by clicking "Restore service dependencies and their settings" in the Publish window.

After clicking, I was able to configure my dependencies without the "Failed to resolve token 'ProfileResourceId'." error.

[image: Service Dependencies Configuration Window]